# angular json related functions against native js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

```
angular.toJson( obj, pretty );
angular.fromJson( json );
```

vs

```
JSON.stringify( obj )
JSON.parse( json )
```

I used to use native ones, but started to use angular ones for consistency. Any other reasons to use those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought was it's related to some test purposes(same case with using $window instead of window). But after looking into source code: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L977

```
function toJson(obj, pretty) {
  if (typeof obj === 'undefined') return undefined;
  if (!isNumber(pretty)) {
    pretty = pretty ? 2 : null;
  }
  return JSON.stringify(obj, toJsonReplacer, pretty);
}
```

Looks like it's a simple wrap for case with undefined object as param.

same for `fromJson`: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L998

```
function fromJson(json) {
  return isString(json)
      ? JSON.parse(json)
      : json;
}
```

so, generally, it's just to remove that checking from app code into framework code.